# Google chart decrease Y axis labels width

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I an trying to draw a chart using Google charts and i am facing an issue that i am not able to decrease the width of X axis labels. I have used *chartArea* in *options* as following. Still i am not able to fix it.

```
options = {
            height : 450,
            width: 1024,
            bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
            bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            chartArea:{left:30,top:10,width:'80%'}              
        };
```

I am getting a result like this :[image: Chart result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several options that are not supported by *Material* charts,

including --> `chartArea.*`

see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

recommend using *Core* chart instead, with the following option...

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['High Blood Pressure', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['Test 1', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['Test 2', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height : 450,
    width: 1024,
    bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
    chartArea:{left:30,top:10,width:'80%'},
    theme: 'material'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes .. it works. You saved my time.  Thanks a lot WhiteHat :)

Comment: Does this work for stacked column chart too? It looks so cool, I tried it but still I see labels getting chopped off

Comment: Interesting... I had the chart in a jquery tabs in a popup and thats where its failing, moving the chart to a separate page works like a charm...

Comment: to give more room to labels, increase --> `chartArea.left`